# Using WCF Service for event handling

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

Presently I have one class which monitor serial ports for incoming data, process the data and raises events through delegates/events based on the received data. This is a stand alone application. Now I have to convert it to a service so that the serial port monitor class will start as a service when the windows starts and a client applications subscribes to the events from either a remote PC or from the local machine. I have seen many articles on using WCF for this kind of applications. But WCF is message based and it will create a service obect when the client is requested. But my requirement is the service should be started automatically and the client application should be able to subscribe for the events of the service class instance which is already created during startup. How can I achieve this using WCF ?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior in WCF is to create a new instance of your service class to handle each incoming request, but you can override this by decorating your class with:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

To get good performance with a Singleton, though, there's a few things you'll need to consider:

- Since you'll likely need to do some configuration of your Singleton instance, you'll probably want to use the `ServiceHost` constructor method that takes a Singleton instance as an argument. (For an example, see [**Figure 8 Initializing and Hosting a Singleton** in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S6)
- Threading: The default threading model (`ConcurrencyMode`) only allows a single thread to have access to your Singleton instance at a time. You may need to look at using `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` to get good performance (which means you'll need to handle threading-related issues yourself).
- Make sure the methods in your Callback contract are marked as `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]` so that publishing events back to the subscribers doesn't cause your service instance to block until the event handler completes. (Using WCF in this way is [covered in detail in this article by Juval Lowy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

Comment: Thank for the reply. I know the singleton. Actually what I am looking is I have one class which does many things. Basically I dont want to alter the class only for WCF. I found think link great "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx". In that the publisher and subsriber are two different services.